# Perfmon - Refresh rate of power meter

Tags: perfmon, power-management, meter

I'm writing a tool to collect information about power consumption of notebooks. I need to measure the current power consumption, and I use Perfmon to do so. But I found a strange bug.
Here is the typical graph of power consumption (this is "Power Meter" - "Power" - "_Total"):

[image]

Measurements are updated about once every 10-15 seconds.

But if the run Everest (or AIDA64) Power Management tab will be updating this more often, the results are more accurate:

[image]

Measurements are updated about once every 1-2 seconds.

I do not understand what happens when we run Everest. I really need to get accurate data.
Do you have any ideas?

I would really appreciate any suggestions in this regard.